# AWS - Sending SMS without subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am working on an app on AWS that needs to send text messages to customers. At times, the app just needs to send a single text message (AWS Transactional SMS may help here), at times it may need to text different groups of people (AWS doesn't seem to have a solution for this use case). It all depends on what the user is doing on the app.

I have explored the possibility of using SNS, but it requires users to be subscribed to a topic, which doesn't work for my use case. I have explored the possibility of using AWS Pinpoint, but it also doesn't seem to apply to my use case. I could use Twilio, but I would prefer to stay within AWS (Additionally, [Twilio runs on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/twilio/))

What is the best way to send text messages in the USA through AWS that doesn't require subscription to a topic?

Answer (score 4):

If someone seeking for the answer of this Qn:

You can send SMS in 2 ways in AWS SNS.

1. Subscribe to a topic that is created in AWS SNS and send sms to all those numbers who had the subscription
2. Send SMS directly to a mobile number

What you need is the 2nd one.

I will demonstrate here how to do that with Ruby language.

Install the gem aws sns:

```
gem install aws-sdk-sns 
require 'aws-sdk-sns'
```

1.Set SNS client

```
@sns_client = Aws::SNS::Client.new(
  region: ENV['AWS_SNS_REGION'],
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_SNS_ACCESS_KEY'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SNS_SECRET_KEY']
)
```

2.Set SNS client attributes

```
@sns_client.set_sms_attributes({
                                 attributes: {
                                   'DefaultSenderID' => SENDER_ID,
                                   'DefaultSMSType' => SMS_TYPE
                                 }
                               })
```

3.Publish SMS

```
otp = (1000..9999).to_a.sample

@sns_client.publish({
                      phone_number: @mobile_no,
                      message: "#{OTM_MSG} #{otp}"
                    })
```

thats it!

OTM_MSG: ‘Your message comes here’

SMS_TYPE : ‘Transactional’ or ‘Promotional’

If you want to send OTP / bank transactions, then it is ‘Transactional’. Else if you want to send some promotional sms of your product then it is ‘Promotional’

SENDER_ID: is the sender id that you have already registered if you want to use your own sender id.

If you don't have sender id skip the step 2 - Set SNS client attributes

AWS_SNS_REGION, AWS_SNS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SNS_SECRET_KEY - are the credentials of your AWS account from where you would like to use SNS.

See the AWS documentation for this here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html
It also provides code for Java language.

If you want to know more I have written an article here:
https://railsdrop.com/2021/03/04/aws-sns-how-to-send-sms/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Publish` action from the SNS service to send a text to a single phone without a topic. You could repeatedly call `Publish` to send texts to multiple phones.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html

---

Use the `CreateTopic`, `Subscribe`, and `Publish` actions from the SNS service to send a text to a multiple phones at once (uses a Topic).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-topic.html